# How To Create Backup Periodically Based On More Frequent Access To A File Using Java Netbeans

Tags: java

I have a project that I have to create a backup periodically based on more frequent access to a file using java netbeans. it will be in client server network. 
for example : a client access a file 5 times in a day, so that file will be backed up to a server database. and some file just accessed 1, 2, 3 or 4 times a day, these will not be backed up.

Comment: I assume this is just an exercise, because only backing up files changed 5 times, but not 4 doesn't make any sense.  Unless you want unreliable backups.

Comment: It will be great if you can add some code and tell us what have you done so far.